# 5th Gen Airport Extreme Randomly drops connection - but only on some devices

Tags: wifi, airport, compatibility

Here's the situation: I am using a brand new MacBook Pro, and thus far all seems well.

I have a 5th Gen Airport Extreme that has worked well for nearly a decade. (I hadn't realized it was so long, but there you are).

So lately what's been happening is my wife's devices seem to randomly lose connections. She has to have our internet connection function, so clearly this is a REAL problem. She is using a ThinkPad / Windows machine and connecting to a work VPN.

The other device she has is a late model iPad mini, which recently lost a zoom meeting.

I have had no problems with the Internet but she seems to run into a problem about once a month, where she gets randomly kicked off the network and it takes a minute for everything to find it again.
Anyhow, I had a few ideas as to what is wrong, but I need some help even figuring out how to diagnose this. Our ISP is Spectrum, and they said all is well with the modem (an Arris DG167OA I think, that is directly connected to the Airport Extreme)

My ideas:

1. Distance. The problem is just that she is in the kitchen about 20 feet from the router, through a couple of walls. The thing is, I have worked out there too (on the terrace) and never had a problem yet.
2. Some weird compatibility issue since the problems seem to come up most often with the Windows machine and recently I was able to get her on the Internet using a local hotspot from my phone (which was set to Wifi)
3. Something I haven't thought of, related to the age of the router.

What I have done: firmware is version 7.8.1, and I am not getting the "update" notice.
Haven't tried hard reset yet, since we need Internet to work (so I likely need to do it at night or something)

I have an airport express I bought also some years ago (it was originally hooked up to the stereo to play music) and maybe that could help extend the network if that's the problem, but do let me know.
Any ideas welcome . Thanks!

Also: if anyone has suggestions for an Apple Router to buy please tell me; the only ones I saw were $500 and that seems crazy compared to what I spent years back. I need a solution that "just works" -- I am not interested in playing Tech Support Guy as I have a job too, you know?

Comment: First, on the devices you are having issues with—can you forget this WiFi connection, then try reconnecting (often fixes issues).
Second, could it be possible that the VPN requires more bandwidth than is allocated?

Comment: haven't tried forgetting yet on some; I'll see what that does...